# Spotify app only showing album cover when stepping with debugger

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, timing

I have built [this Spotify app](https://github.com/chirpradio/chirpradio-spotify), that searches for an album with the [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/search/). I have instantiated a `Player` object from the album, but it does not show the album cover as the background image under normal operation. **But** if I create a breakpoint on [this line](https://github.com/chirpradio/chirpradio-spotify/blob/master/app/app.js#L59) and step line by line, the album cover *does* display properly. I even [changed](https://github.com/chirpradio/chirpradio-spotify/blob/master/app/spotify-metadata.js#L31) the Spotify API `GET` request to `async: false` to eliminate weird timing issues. Any help would be appreciated.

**Images**

1. [Working when stepping through code with debugger](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s8/sh/96a211ec-3fd7-468b-9c6b-e6ad2395684c/8f48da77190ecccbaa348899eb89f2bb)
2. [Not working when not stepping with debugger](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s8/sh/5c5c83b6-7658-4d3b-930a-38a2d5fef034/afe104e14c8ad9cb33f0926261bdac10)